# Limit quaternion pitch

Tags: java, opengl, angle, quaternions, pitch

I want to limit the pitch of my camera to +/-90 degrees. How would i do that.

```
public boolean mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.x / -1f), Vector4f.UP), rotation);
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.y / 1f), rotation.getRight(null)), temp);


    updateMatrix();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I usually store and limit camera orientation outside the quaternion, recreating the quaternion on change or use. I realize that does not answer your question but it might solve your immediate problem... Cheers!

Comment: if you have a quaternion and convert it to yaw-pitch-roll, pitch is *always* -90..90 degrees. if you take a set of angles with a >90 pitch, convert it to a quaternion, and then back to angles, it'll wrap the pitch and use yaw to get "to the other side"